# Rails is it possible to have a link_to that passes param to jquery datatable filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 5 and Jquery Datatables in an app. I have a filter field on my datatable. I would like for people to be able to click on a tag and get the main table filtered by that tag. The seemingly easy way to do it would be to have a `link_to` like this:

```
posts_path(post: {filter: 'science'})
```

This creates the URL like:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?post%5Bfilter%5D=science
```

I then have this in my controller `index` action:

```
@posts = Post.all
@filter = post_params[:filter]
```

Which is using the standard strong params method like:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:filter ...)
end
```

Then in the Javascript for the DataTable I did this:

```
$('#posts_table').dataTable({
         saveState: true,
         "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
         search: {
             search: '<%= @filter %>'
         },
         "columnDefs": [
             {
                 "targets": [-1],
                 "visible": false,
                 "searchable": true
             }
         ]
 });
```

It works great!! The page loads with the table filtered on the search term and the term appears in the search text box. But when I call the index page without any params it fails:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts

ActionController::ParameterMissing at /posts
 param is missing or the value is empty: post
```

which I get because no params are being sent but I'm calling the params method. Is there a simple way to fix this? i.e. could I make the default route have a default param with an empty string as the search term? What would the correct syntax for that route be? I was thinking I could set the params to '' if undefined but not sure how to do that with Strong Params in a way that would not compromise security.

Answer (score 0):

Well I knew this couldn't be too difficult and was probably over-thinking it. I finally just made a route for tags thus:

```
get 'tags', to: 'posts#by_tag', as: :filter, :constraints  => { :filter => /[^\/]+/ }
```

Then I added a controller action called `by_tag` like this:

```
def by_tag
  @posts = Post.all
  @filter = post_params[:filter]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :index }
  end
end
```

then to create my tag links I just do something like:

```
tags.each do |t|
  link_to t.name, filter_path(post: {filter: t.name})
end
```

which creates links like:

```
http://localhost:3000/tags?post%5Bfilter%5D=9500XL
```

And with the JavaScript mentioned in the question I get the table loaded with the filter applied in the search field.

Something about the `by_tag` action feels a bit un-rails-ish. I feel like I'm missing something simple that would allow me to leverage the `index` action for this. If anyone has a better answer I'd love to know.